# Dependency Injection using Unity is null in constructor c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

```
container.RegisterType<ICustomer<CustomerViewModel>, CustomersCore>();
container.RegisterType<IDocument<DocumentViewModel>, DocumentsCore>();
container.Resolve<DocumentBusiness>();
```

My question , do we really need to include Resolve,
because I noticed that CustomerController 
    `container.RegisterType<ICustomer<CustomerViewModel>, CustomersCore>` 
IS NOT NULL IN `CustomerController` constructor even without Resolve

while DocumentBusiness.cs

```
`container.RegisterType<IDocument<DocumentViewModel>, DocumentsCore>();
```

IS NULL in DocumentBusiness constructor without Resolve

Whats the difference , the other one    `<ICustomer>` is being used by MVC Controller class and the other one    `<IDocument>` is being used by an C# class?

Summary of issue

1. `CustomerController.cs` perfectly working , not null in constructor
2. `DocumentBusiness.cs`, not working , null in constructor unless Resolve is used.

Is this normal?

Comment: Still a bit unclear what you are asking. Show that classes that depend on these abstractions and their constructors

Comment: as long as you have added all the bindings and all your contracts were resolved, you should not get a null reference.